# overloading istream operator >> with getline gives error

Tags: c++

I really don't know why, but I'm struggling with my >> operator getting it to work properly with getline.
Basically, I have a command class in which I want to assign the user input to its `chain` attribute and after that I want to split user input with space as delimiter to its string array `param`

For now, I just want to get the first one to work correctly, for the split, I'll do it later with `strok`.

**Edit:**

My error:

```
Commande.cpp: In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Commande&)':
Commande.cpp:82:39: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::__cxx11::string&, int)'
    stream.getline(commande.chaine, 256);
```

**Command.cpp**

```
Command::Command() {
}

Command::Command(std::string _chain) {
    chaine = _chain;
}


Command::Command(const Command& orig) {
}

Command::~Command() {
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &stream, Command& command)
{
   stream.getline(command.chain, 256); 
   return stream;
}
```

**Command.h**

```
#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Command.h"

public:

    std::string chain;    

    std::string param[10];

    Command();

    Command(std::string _chain); 

    Command(const Command& orig);

    virtual ~Command();

private:

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, Command&);
};

#endif /* COMMAND_H */
```

**Main.cpp**

```
include "command.h" 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Command command;

    std::cin >> command;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Looks like a typo.  `#include <string.h>` should be `#include <string>`

Comment: maybe its just due to my ignorance, but I would never mix `getline` and `operator<<` in that way

Comment: Commande.cpp: In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Commande&)':
Commande.cpp:82:39: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::__cxx11::string&, int)'
    stream.getline(commande.chaine, 256);

Comment: please add the error message to the quesiton

Comment: I don't see anyone including Command.h except Command.h. Without [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) this will get really messy really fast. Come to think of it, command.h looks more like I'd expect from command.cpp. I may have fallen victim to a typo.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm pretty sure OP swapped them when composing their question.

Comment: Typo: Command::Commande --> Command::Command (no 'e')

Comment: I don't see a resize of your string to make sure that it can hold the line that's about to be read; meaning you're about to smash your stack (or heap - depends how lucky you are)

Comment: `std::istream::getline` takes a `char*` not a `std::string`. Use `std::getline` instead.

Comment: Why the limit for `getline`?  I recommend using `std::getline(stream, command.chain);`

Comment: I have done this before, but I wanted to use >> instead.

Comment: I hope that your `Command.h` and `Command.cpp` are actually the other way around.  And that you're actually compiling `Command.cpp` and not `Commande.cpp` which your error indicates, but you didn't show.

Comment: yes, yes, it was just a tepo while I was coping my code

Answer (score 0):

I changed my fonction as @Thomas Mattews recommanded and it works perfectly. thumbs up for all the other answers too.

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &stream, Command& command)
{
   std::getline(stream, command.chain);
   return stream;
}
```